# Error creating vocabulary from big text file on disk

Tags: text2vec

I try to perform example from https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/text2vec/vignettes/files-multicore.html but with my file "text" - 3.7Gb plain text, build from Wikipedia XML dump with Perl script from here - http://mattmahoney.net/dc/textdata.html

```
setwd("c:/rtest")
library(text2vec)
library(doParallel)
N_WORKERS = 2
registerDoParallel(N_WORKERS)
it_files_par = ifiles_parallel(file_paths = "text")
it_token_par = itoken_parallel(it_files_par, preprocessor = tolower, tokenizer = word_tokenizer)
vocab = create_vocabulary(it_token_par)
```

This causes error:

```
Error in unserialize(socklist[[n]]) : error reading from connection
```

I have 8Gb RAM, word2vec model from this file is created without any errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all it doesn't make sense to use parallel iterators on a single file - each file processed in a separate R worker process. So here it will be worse than just `itoken`. Also it involves sending result from each worker to the master process. Here we see that result it too big to be send through socket.
Long story short - just use `itoken` or split your file into several smaller files.